# How would one access values on the stack within an ARM subroutine?

Tags: assembly, arm

So I want to read in 10 ints from the command line and then print the sum of those values via a subroutine.

I have the following pertinent code:

```
...

sub sp, sp, #40 // making room on the stack
mov r4, sp      // use r4 as our working register for where we are in our space
   loop:
      (looping through this 10 times)
      ldr r0, =rdfmt
      mov r1, r4
      bl scanf
      add r4, r4 #4
   done:
      bl sum
sum:
   push {lr}
   (how do I load those back in from the stack?)

...
```

In my sum subroutine I would like to iterate back through the stack 10 times and get the sum of the values I just read in. How do you do that?

Comment: You fall through into `sum` again after it returns...  (I guess you left out the `bx lr` or `pop {pc}` at the bottom of your first function, like you left out the loop branch at the bottom of your loop?)  And if `sum` is a leaf function, it doesn't need to `push {lr}`, it can just `bx lr` or `mov pc, lr`

Answer (score 5):

Unlike most CISC CPUs (x86, m68k ...) ARM CPUs do not modify the stack pointer (`sp`) on a function call. However they subtract 4 from the stack pointer when doing a `push` instruction.

When doing the `bl sum` instruction 10 integers are located in the memory starting at the address the `sp` register points to. After the `push {lr}` instruction these integers are still in that location but the value of `sp` is 4 less than before - so the 10 integers are now found at the address `sp+4`.

Load the first integer from the address `sp+4` into a register. Then load the integer from address `sp+8` into another register and add both registers. Repeat this with the integer at the address `sp+12` and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! So big picture I am loading the stack values via `ldr r0, [sp, #+4]` but this appears to be causing a seg fault in my subroutine whenever I try and run it. Have I made a syntax error there?